# gojs custom binding passed to function as part of textBlock

Tags: gojs

using GOJS is is possible to pass a  binding parameter to a function?

I would like to use this passed var to change the font type group returned for example in the below code the `aplha` parameter is passed back to the node that calls the `textStyle()` function that would do an if/else based on the passed value.

```
      myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("Source",
        $(go.Node, "Auto", nodeStyle(),
            $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle",
                { fill: bluegrad },
                new go.Binding("fill", "color")
            ),
            $(go.TextBlock, textStyle(alpha),
                new go.Binding("text", "text"),
                new go.Binding("alpha", "alpha")
            ),
            makePort("T", go.Spot.Top, false, true),
            makePort("L", go.Spot.Left, true, true),
            makePort("R", go.Spot.Right, true, true),
            makePort("B", go.Spot.Bottom, true, true)
        ));


       //.....
            myPalette =
                $(go.Palette, "myPaletteDiv",  // must name or refer to the DIV HTML element
                    {
                        nodeTemplateMap: myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap,  // share the templates used by myDiagram
                        model: new go.GraphLinksModel([  // specify the contents of the Palette
                            { category: "Source", text: "source", alpha:"fontGroupA"},
                            { category: "Source", text: "source", alpha:"fontGroupB"},
                            ])
                    });


      //.....
        // Common text styling
        function textStyle(alpha) {
            console.log("value passed:"+alpha);
            return {
                margin: 6,
                wrap: go.TextBlock.WrapFit,
                textAlign: "center",
                editable: true,
                font: bigfont
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE**

Based on Walter's answer below, I added a callback and bindings, that now works.

```
//.....
                myPalette =
                    $(go.Palette, "myPaletteDiv",  // must name or refer to the DIV HTML element
                        {
                            nodeTemplateMap: myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap,  // share the templates used by myDiagram
                            model: new go.GraphLinksModel([  // specify the contents of the Palette
                                { category: "Source", text: "source_a", css:"fontGroupA"},
                                { category: "Source", text: "source_b", css:"fontGroupB"},
                                ])
                        });


//...
$(go.TextBlock,
                            {
                               // Default settings // 
                               font: "bold 15pt Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
                                stroke: lightText,
                                margin: 8,
                                maxSize: new go.Size(100, NaN),
                                wrap: go.TextBlock.WrapFit,
                                editable: true
                            },
                            new go.Binding("font", "css", function(v) {return cssStyle(v).font}).makeTwoWay(),
                            new go.Binding("stroke", "css", function(v) {return cssStyle(v).stroke}).makeTwoWay()
                        )


   // ...
 function cssStyle(theStyle) {

        if (theStyle === "fontGroupA"){
            return {
                margin: 6,
                wrap: go.TextBlock.WrapFit,
                textAlign: "right",
                editable: true,
                font: bigfont,
                stroke: "red"
            }
        }else if (theStyle === "fontGroupB"){
            return {
                margin: 6,
                wrap: go.TextBlock.WrapFit,
                textAlign: "left",
                editable: true,
                font: smallfont,
                stroke: "blue"
            }
        }else {
             return {
                margin: 6,
                wrap: go.TextBlock.WrapFit,
                textAlign: "center",
                editable: true,
                font: midfont
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I should point out that

```
    $(go.TextBlock, textStyle(alpha),
      new go.Binding("alpha", "alpha"))
```

is incorrect.  There is no **TextBlock.alpha** property, so you cannot bind to that property.  If you have tried your code you should have seen that error in the console.

Second, it isn't clear where you want to get the value for `alpha`.  Your code is evaluating it at the time you define the template, so that looks like an error to me.  Maybe you have its value set earlier.  Still, it would be a specific value at template definition time.

Third, you could have separate bindings for each of those **TextBlock** properties that you might set based on the value of `data.alpha`.  Each binding would use a conversion function that chose the appropriate value given the value of `data.alpha`.

Your `textStyle` function didn't produce different values based on the alpha argument, but I could imagine something like:

```
    $(go.TextBlock,
      new go.Binding("text"),
      new go.Binding("font", "alpha", computeFontForAlpha))
```

where `computeFontForAlpha` returns the desired CSS font string depending on the value of `data.alpha`.